# Why cannot I pass instances of the same class in the class constructor?

Tags: java

```
public Fraction (int a1 , int b1)   {
    a = a1;
    b = b1;
}

Fraction fr = new Fraction (new  Fraction(1,1), new Fraction(2,2)    )
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but you would need a separate constructor that takes 2 `Fraction`s as parameters.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Answer (score 6):

> Can this [...] be called like this [...]

Of course not.  Java is a statically typed language, and this constructor expects `int` types:

```
public Fraction (int a1 , int b1)
```

However, on this line you're providing it with `Fraction` types:

```
new Fraction (new Fraction(1,1), new Fraction(2,2))
```

That won't work for exactly the reason the compiler is telling you.  There is no constructor on `Fraction` which matches the types of the arguments specified.

(The two *inner* constructor calls on that line will work.  The *outer* one is the one that's failing.)

> Is there a way to make this work?

Depends on how you define your constructors You *can* define two constructors in your class:

```
public Fraction (int a1 , int b1)
{
    // ...
}

public Fraction (Fraction a1 , Fraction b1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can construct an instance of a `Fraction` object with either constructor, which would make that line valid.  What you *do* inside that second constructor is up to you.

Comment: A fraction of two fractions is well defined in math.

Comment: @laune: That's nice.  But what does that have to do with Java constructors?

Comment: I was referring to "What you *do* inside that second constructor is up to you". Of course, assuming that the program is intended to conform to generally accepted principles. - See Sasha's A below.

Comment: @laune there's no `public Fraction(Fraction, Fraction)` constructor in OP's code. Unless you provide such constructor, what OP tries is unachievable, despite if it's mathematically possible. That's David's lesson.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You are telling me things I know - what's the point? If David writes "What you do - is up to you", then this is either absolutely redundant or it may provoke a comment. That's all - take it or leave it.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work, create one more overloaded constructor that accepts two `Fraction` arguments:

```
public Fraction(Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {
    this(f1.a*f2.b, f1.b*f2.a); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its possible only if you write 2 overloaded Constructor :

`public Fraction (int a1 , int b1)`

and

`public Fraction (Fraction f1 , Fraction f2)`